# WPF Theming and Colours

Tags: wpf, theming, color-palette, solidcolorbrush

I dont know if this is possible, or how to achieve it, but I wanted to ask the question to see if someone has done something similar in WPF.

Currently we have a themed app. There are Light, Dark and Monochrome themes. Each theme has a set of defined colours used for a variety of things.

We had word lately that we would like to make the app more 'customisable' in that there is a wish for users to create their own theme (even including their own logo branding too)

My question here is that since we currently define so many colours for each theme, would it be possible to define say a base colour, then when we use the colour, change it (darker or lighter) to achieve the same look and feel?

Example of the current colour definitions:

```
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueDark25" Color="#F6F7F9" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueDark50" Color="#ECEFF3" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueDark100" Color="#DADEE8" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueDark150" Color="#C7CEDC" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueDark200" Color="#B4BED1" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueDark250" Color="#A1ADC5" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueDark300" Color="#8F9DB9" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueDark350" Color="#7C8DAE" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueDark400" Color="#697DA2" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueDark450" Color="#576C97" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueDark500" Color="#445C8B" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueDark600" Color="#364A6F" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueDark700" Color="#182031" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueDark900" Color="#07090E" />
```

Is it possible to allow the user (or have a predefined) 'BlueDark' definition (just 1), but then manipulate it darker or lighter depending on the usage? So it would be possible for the user to define, say 2 or 3 main colours, and the app does the rest for them?

I appreciate that I would not be able to match exactly the colours shown here, but I am thinking there must be some way of doing it.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I've implemented something like this. You can merge an uncompiled resource dictionary. Our app had base resource dictionaries and merged a custom .xaml file if it existed. There was a little app allowed the user to pick colours and wrote a line into the file for each. Paste in paths from inkscape for logo. For a small fee, the company would build you a lovely custom logo. You could enter argb values. Colour contrast is advisable rather than just light Vs dark . Complimentary colours have maximum colour contrast.

Answer (score -1):

You could set the `Opacity` of a `Brush` to a value between `0` and `1`. This lets you define a base colour with an opacity of 1 and then define additional brushes that are shades of the base, e.g.:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Blue" Color="Blue" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="LighterBlue" Color="Blue" Opacity="0.7" />
...
```

Apart from this solution, I don't think there is an easy way to generate an entire colour scheme using only a base colour in XAML. You might be able to it by generating the brushes programmatically.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of setting the Opacity even in 0.1 increments to achieve a range of tones of the same colour. 
I didnt know if there was a more 'technical' approach to it :D

Comment: Not without generating the colours/brushes programmatically somehow.

Comment: Opacity is something different than brightness. Think about a control with a semi-transparent Background in a layout Panel with semi-transparent Background. Colors would add in all kinds of unexpected ways. This is not at all a "solution".